# How to implement the below feature using java8

Tags: java

How to implement this in java8 and anyone please help me,i tried using streams but not working may be syntactically i was wrong.

I have tried:

```
list.stream().map(res->.get(s)).filter(res->res!=null && res.equalIgnoreCase("something"))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a Q&A forum.

Comment: Show your attempts

Comment: Please post proper code, your last if condition is incomplete and what is the type declaration of `list`. You should also include what you have tried with streams.

Comment: Your code has missed `)` at if statement. Also parameter should be passed to `equals ()`

Comment: if(res!=null && res.equalIgnoreCase("something"){

Comment: list.stream().map(res->.get(s)).filter(res->res!=null && res.equalIgnoreCase("something"))

Comment: Thank you for the correction and the attempt. Please post such updates as edits to your question rather than as comments so we have everything in one place (this time only I did it for you). It’s much nicer, and you generally cannot expect people to read through the comments in order to understand your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a new java8 `Collection.removeIf()` method. The method works by applying the condition provided in the [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) instance to all the elements in the Collection on which it is invoked. The elements which satisfy the condition are retained while the remaining are removed from the Collection.

```
list.removeIf(item -> {
  String res = map.get(item);

  return res != null && res.equalsIgnoreCase("smt");
});
```

Comment: ... or `list.removeIf(item -> map.containsKey(item) && map.get(item).equalsIgnoreCase("smt"));`

Comment: @Naman It's better to use one operation on the map instead of two. In terms of performance

Comment: then would you prefer using `list.removeIf(item -> "smt".equalsIgnoreCase(map.get(item)));` ?

Comment: @Naman It looks better, but this bunch of code is not quite obvious. Another programmer will have to stop and think about what's going on here.